# how to next line in tabbar in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using reactjs ant design. I want to type 234 in first line and in next line type followers.how to next line in tab bar.

I want to type like this 
"333
followers "

```js
import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

function callback(key) {
  console.log(key);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" onChange={callback}>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">Content of Tab Pane 1</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">Content of Tab Pane 2</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">Content of Tab Pane 3</TabPane>
  </Tabs>,
  mountNode);
```

Comment: What do u mean by first and second line?Can you reframe your question with clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass react components to the `tab` prop on the `<TabPane />`  component (not just strings).

This basically means that you can  pass JSX markup into this prop - which will allow you to easly control the style and layout of the tab-bar's content.

For example - if I understand correctly what you are trying to achive - you can do [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y74p20l6k):

```
 <TabPane
      tab={
            <div>
              <div>234</div>
              <div>Followers</div>
            </div>
         }
          key="1"
        >
          Content of Tab Pane 1
        </TabPane>
```

Here is a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y74p20l6k) based on the example you provided.

Hope this helps :)